# password on nfc tag?

Tags: security, tags, passwords, nfc

I am looking to implement nfc tags on some of my sites with general information text written to the tags. The catch is I only want certain people to be able to read the tag. So in a way I would like the user to scan the tag and be prompted for a password before being able to read the tag. Is this possible ? Open to any ideas as long as the tag can hold enough text approx 300-400 characters. Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: This type of open-ended question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you're having problems with a particular library (e.g. you have code and it doesn't work), we can likely help you, but this question will elicit mostly opinions and will probably get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You might encrypt the text that you store on the tag. When the user reads the tag, enters the password, the text can be decrypted using the PW.

Depending what level of security is needed and what complexity in the implentation / roll out is acceptable, you can go  for a symetrical encryption (e.g. AES) or for asymetric encryption (e.g. public key encryption such as RSA).